# How do I collapse space when it isn't on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I make it if the display is style="display:none" for each column to have each column not take up blank space and just disappear altogether? When I currently attempt to do it, it still shows the space being taken up. I'm struggling to make this collapse when not being used.

How would I make it if the display is style="display:none" for each column to have each column not take up blank space and just disappear altogether? When I currently attempt to do it, it still shows the space being taken up. I'm struggling to make this collapse when not being used.

Edit: The more I read on it, the display:none won't work because the scroll left to right off the page is an inline element which overrides the display:none.  So basically, what is the work around to have BOTH a left to right scroll off the page and make items in that scroll display:none?

```
<script>function hawks() {
  var x = document.getElementById("hawksSalary");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } {
var hawks = document.getElementById("AtlantaHawks");
if (x.style.display === "block") {
hawks.style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else {
hawks.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
}
}
</script>

<script>
function nets() {
  var x = document.getElementById("netsSalary");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } {
var nets = document.getElementById("BrooklynNets");
if (x.style.display === "block") {
nets.style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else {
nets.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
}


}
</script>

<script>function celtics() {
  var x = document.getElementById("celticsSalary");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } {
var celtics = document.getElementById("BostonCeltics");
if (x.style.display === "block") {
celtics.style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else {
celtics.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
}

}
</script>

<style>
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row > * {
  flex: 0 0 25vw;
}}</style>


        <center><header><h2>NBA Trade Maker</h2></center>
            <nav>
<center>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Atlantic Division</th>
<th>Central Division</th>
<th>Southeast Division</th>
<th>Northwest Division</th>
<th>Southwest Division</th>
<th>Pacific Division</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="BostonCeltics" onclick="celtics()">Boston Celtics</td>
<td>Chicago Bulls</td>
<td id="AtlantaHawks" onclick="hawks()">Atlanta Hawks</td>
<td>Denver Nuggets</td>
<td>Dallas Mavericks</td>
<td>Golden State Warriors</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="BrooklynNets" onclick="nets()">Brooklyn Nets</td>
<td>Cleveland Cavaliers</td>
<td>Charlotte Hornets</td>
<td>Minnesota Timberwolves</td>
<td>Houston Rockets</td>
<td>Los Angeles Clippers</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="NYKnicks" onclick="knicks()">New York Knicks</td>
<td>Detroit Pistons</td>
<td>Miami Heat</td>
<td>Oklahoma City Thunder</td>
<td>Memphis Grizzlies</td>
<td>Los Angeles Lakers</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Philadelphia 76ers</td>
<td>Indiana Pacers</td>
<td>Orlando Magic</td>
<td>Portland Trail Blazers</td>
<td>New Orleans Pelicans</td>
<td>Phoenix Suns</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Toronto Raptors</td>
<td>Milwaukee Bucks</td>
<td>Washington Wizards</td>
<td>Utah Jazz</td>
<td>San Antonio Spurs</td>
<td>Sacramento Kings</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div id="hawksSalary" style="display:none"><h2>Atlanta Hawks</h2>
    <p>Trae Young (Salary Here) Send To:
<select>
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select></p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p id="traeYoungToCeltics" style="display:none">Trae Young</p>
    <div id="celticsSalary" style="display:none"><h2>Boston Celtics</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div id="netsSalary" style="display:none"><h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column 5</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column 6</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column 7</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column 8</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set `"display:hidden"` instead of `"display:none"`.